# Flutter does not apply firebase filter with integers

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to request data from firebase and apply filters using where and display them in a listView with help of Stream Builder. But the filters with an integer is not working and those with a string is working. I added a filter where the cost field has to be greater than 100, but it gives me all of them even if their cost is less. There is no error in the stacktrace. Here is the relevant code:-

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Planes").where("cost",isGreaterThan:100).snapshots(),//I have tried making 100 a string
                builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                          child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    ViewPlane(plane: snapshot,index:index,email: email,)));
                          },
                          leading: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                          title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index][' destination']),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['airport']),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
            ),
```

Any help will be appreciated
EDIT
Here is the image of database as per request
[Dtabase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVrih.jpg)

Comment: does cost have a value of int in the database?

Comment: yeah. there are 4 documents. Each have an integer cost value.

Comment: add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: I have added the image now.@PeterHaddad

Comment: For questions or concerns pertaining to Firebase products and services, I would like to direct you to the [Firebase Support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0). As they would be better suited in providing answers to your Firebase inquiries. You may also address your question to the [Flutter issue tracker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) to gain more traction into your issue.